# Azure Cloud Service I can not get IPv6 address from REMOTE_ADDR nor HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: azure, ip, ipv6

I have correctly managed to get the IPv4 address from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or REMOTE_ADDR headers from each request hitting the Azure cloud service I have deployed.
However I can not get the IPv6 from the same headers for any of the requests that hit the service.

is this a limitation of the Azure Cloud Services? or I have to enable something on the azure cloud service configuration?

thank you

EDIT: I tried it myself as well from a box with valid IPv6; those headers do not have my IPv6 in them, only my IPv4.

so it is correct to say azure cloud service can not detect/read the IPv6 from the requests coming from clients with valid Ipv6 addresses? or is it possible that I still do something wrong or another configuration has to be set on the cloud service level?

Comment: Are you connecting via IPv6? What actually appears in these headers?

Comment: the clients are doing an http GET over port 80 to domain url.
I see only IPv4 in the mentioned headers no IPv6

Comment: How do you know the clients are using IPv6, then? Maybe they are actually using IPv4.

Comment: it is true I do not know, but this service has lots of clients, it is quite impossible that all of them are IPv4.

Comment: In that case, try it yourself. You do have IPv6 at home, don't you? If you don't, you need to spend an hour yelling at your ISP. They should have rolled it out to you years ago.

Comment: yes I tried it myself, and I do have IPv6; those headers do not have my IPv6 in them only my IPv4

Answer (score 1):

Azure Cloud Service doesn't support IPv6 now.

Currently, only Azure Machine with Load Balance can support public IPv6 Address.